# How to build offline web applications in IE8?

Tags: html, internet-explorer-8, offline, web

Is it really true that there is no way to support an offline web application using IE8? I wonder how people/companies are getting around this problem (no IE8 support for HTML5 offline features) if they absolutely need to use an IE browser (not IE10) and need to use it when no net connectivity exists. I realize there are plenty of rich client solutions but am curious about any lightweight solutions whereby IE8 would access *something* like applicationCache. Apparently Google Gears is no longer a solution for this problem. Any other third party solution people would recommend?

Any suggestions would be helpful!

Thanks.

Comment: Why is 'Google Gears is no longer a solution' it's never going to be light weight. Only Fat Clients do this kind of stuff. By trying to keep it light weight you will end up with a complicated unwanted data structures.

Comment: @Shahzeb Probably because Google Gears is no longer maintained/supported

Comment: IE users will always miss out on modern practices since IE is always years behind all the other browsers.

Answer (score 0):

The only currently practical option is [Chrome Frame](http://www.google.com/chromeframe/), but this is almost equivalent to just installing a whole new browser.

Comment: Thanks robert. Good to know about Frame. Looking into whether that's an option from us now, but yeah ... if it's just like using Chrome then it may not make sense (IT dept-wise that is).

Comment: @rubioriflestherock You could try pointing your IT dept at [this blog post](http://blog.zeltser.com/post/2430558151/enterprise-google-chrome-deployment), but it may not have all the options they need.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps I'm misunderstanding the concept of offline web app, but we routinely use [HTML Applications](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms536496%28VS.85%29.aspx) (HTA) to create web apps that operate client-side, accessing the file system and local data stores, and automating local apps.